Where can I find a searchable online text of the Bhagavad Gita?
I want to be able to search across the Bhagavad Gita in Sanskrit for certain words or phrases. I've seen webpages where you have to click to different pages to navigate through. But I want to be able to search across the entire text at once. Is any such resource avilable?

If you don't mind using a pdf version, here's a link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://assets.website-files.com/61c9a61843fdbc5e413552d8/625b7ff46f276a1953b46fe5_Bhagavad-Gita%2520As%2520It%2520Is%2520(Original%25201972%2520Edition).pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiH5JPL5qKHAxWArokEHW2LAbc4ChAWegQIDxAB&usg=AOvVaw1caZE70wazPjVCvuzi_mW-

Sanskrit Original:
Bhagavadgītā
Sanskrit with sandhi-vigraha and anvaya:
Bhagavadgītā — sandhi-vigraha and anvaya
BORI critical edition Sanskrit IAST:
GRETIL

Thanks for that anvaya link!
